# Duality principle (in projective geometry sense)

Tags: projective-geometry, axioms, duality-theorems

So, we know that duality principle stands in geometry of projective planes.

- Do we know some other sets of axioms and the spaces that are generated by them, where the duality also applies?
- If they exist, do they all have some common properties and what should it be?

I hope my questions are understandable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about your question. But more concretely, there is a very nice duality for conics in the plane : the dual curve of a conic is a conic.

Comment: Any system of axioms that are symmetric in their handling of two primative elements will have a duality principle. It is relatively easy to come up with such systems. It is hard to come up with such systems where the theory described is interesting.

Comment: Then the question is - do we know some interesting sets that have duality in it.